# Include two variables in a logfile name to be set

Tags: string, windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, substitution

I have been trying to get the following to work but no avail

```
$SITE = 'APAC'
$interval = 'Friday'

    Write-host c:\becnet\xenapp\'logvdareboot_'$SITE'_'$interval'_servers.txt'
    $logfile = c:\becnet\xenapp\'logvdareboot_'$SITE'_'$interval'_servers.txt'
    Out-File $logfile
```

This outputs the following:

```
c:\becnet\xenapp\logvdareboot_NP_ASH_ODD_servers.txt
c:\becnet\xenapp\logvdareboot_$SITE_$interval_servers.txt : The term
'c:\becnet\xenapp\logvdareboot_$SITE_$interval_servers.txt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At D:\Rohit\cr.ps1:283 char:14
+ ...  $logfile = c:\becnet\xenapp\'logvdareboot_'$SITE'_'$interval'_server ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\becnet\xenap...val_servers.txt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The line of code that outputs the string i need to use is displayed correctly, however i am unable to assign it to make it name a file.
I know that this may come across as a silly one, but i have spend days now trying to figure this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"c:\becnet\xenapp\logvdareboot_${SITE}_${interval}_servers.txt"` should do it

Comment: Thanks a lot @SantiagoSquarzon, it works like a charm. what is the logic behind the squiggly brackets? I had no clue about this one.

Comment: They are enclosed so PowerShell parses the exact name of the variables, otherwise, the variables would become `$SITE_` and `$interval_servers`. You can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#variable-names-that-include-special-characters